# Erro ao tentar hospedar app no itunes

Tags: php, mobile, apple, embarcadero, itunes

Fizemos um app para iPhone com Embarcadero xe10 + PHP, mas ao tentar hospeda-lo em:

Ele foi recusado por não ter suporte a IPV6.

Entrei no site 
http://validador.ipv6.br/index.php?site=www.useunic.com.br&lang=pt
e verifiquei que não tem suporte a acesso por IPV6.

A Apple exige que meu aplicativo funcione em uma rede Ipv6, conforme site acima.

Nesse host hospedamos apenas os arquivos php que são utilizados no app, existe alguma configuração que podemos fazer para corrigir isso, pois entrei em contato com a hospedagem e eles não tem suporte ipv6.

Segue retorno do itunes sobre o app:

```
De Apple
2. 1 PERFORMANCE: APP COMPLETENESS
Performance - 2.1


We discovered one or more bugs in your app when reviewed on iPad running iOS 10.2.1 on Wi-Fi connected to an IPv6 network.

Specifically, your app produced an error when we attempted to log in with the demo account you provided.

Please see attached screenshots for details.

Next Steps

Please run your app on a device while connected to an IPv6 network (all apps must support IPv6) to identify any issues, then revise and resubmit your app for review.

If we misunderstood the intended behavior of your app, please reply to this message in Resolution Center to provide information on how these features were intended to work.

For new apps, uninstall all previous versions of your app from a device, then install and follow the steps to reproduce the issue. For updates, install the new version as an update to the previous version, then follow the steps to reproduce the issue.

Resources

For information about supporting IPv6 Networks, please refer to Supporting IPv6 DNS64/NAT64 Networks and About Networking.
```

Comment: Existe uma gambiarra, você pode utilizar o CloudFlare, ele servirá como um proxy, ele suporta o IPv4 e o IPv6, mesmo que o você somente suporte o IPv4. Mas, aconselho que criptografe de maneira assimetria os dados, ao menos de login/cadastro. Dessa forma nem mesmo o CloudFlare saberá os dados que foram enviados, basta incluir uma chave pública no aplicativo, segurança nunca é de mais. ;)

Comment: Boa tarde!
Cara, na empresa em que trabalhava passamos pelo mesmo problema que você e para solucionar o problema trocamos o plano da hospedagem para um que suporte o IPv6

Comment: Remova esse registro AAAA nas configurações de seu domínio do site do provedor de domínio, e faça alguns testes, vi pessoas comentando a respeito, mas nunca cheguei a testar de fato.

Comment: A resposta é simples, você precisa de um host com suporte a IPV6,  e mais, seu servidor web precisa responder em IPV6 também (address binding).

O Cloudflare pode ser uma boa solução, porém terás problemas com timeout caso tenha requisições muito longas.
Ele também não suporta outros sockets além da porta 80 e 443 e trafega apenas TCP.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Desde junho de 2016, a Apple exigiu que os aplicativos da apple store tenham suporte à IPv6-only,  que é basicamente redes que não utilizam tunelamento ou proxy IPv4.

> However, if your app utilizes IPv4-specific APIs or hard-coded IP addresses, you will need to make changes. 
>   https://developer.apple.com/support/ipv6/

Ou seja, se sua aplicação possui um direcionamento específico à um IP, como por exemplo uma abertura de socket, ou um acesso que utilize diretamente um IP irá cair nessa regra.

Na documentação ainda diz:

> Não é necessário remover da sua aplicação todas as referências para
>   construtores IPv4-only. É aceitável ter tais referências e usar
>   construções somente para IPv4, desde que se comportem corretamente em
>   um ambiente somente IPv6. IMPORTANTE: Encorajamos você a adotar APIs
>   agnósticas de endereço-amigável ao invés de manter caminhos de código
>   separados para IPv4 e IPv6.
>   (tradução pessoal)

APIs agnósticas, são domínios que respondem tanto em IPv6 como em IPv4, ao invés de IPv4 estáticos.

Para realizar os testes de compatibilidade você deve seguir as instruções dessa página da documentação de apoio da Apple https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/NetworkingInternetWeb/Conceptual/NetworkingOverview/UnderstandingandPreparingfortheIPv6Transition/UnderstandingandPreparingfortheIPv6Transition.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010220-CH213-SW16

Se sua aplicação precisa suportar IPv4 (um aplicativo de conexão ssh por exemplo) você precisa aplicar algumas modificações para suporte ao DNS64/NAT64 para sintetizar o IPv4 em IPv6, a técnica está descrita nessa página de documentação: https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/NetworkingInternetWeb/Conceptual/NetworkingOverview/UnderstandingandPreparingfortheIPv6Transition/UnderstandingandPreparingfortheIPv6Transition.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010220-CH213-SW1

Para mais informações acesse:

https://developer.apple.com/support/ipv6/

Além disso, seu servidor deve  ser acessível via IPv6, para isso você pode utilizar CDNs como a [Cloudflare Inc.](https://cloudflare.com) que permitem o tráfego via IPv6 sem que você tenha entradas 'AAAA'. Porém, atente-se pois há limitações como timeout de conexão, chamadas que demorem muito a responder podem cair no erro [524](https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/articles/200171926-Error-524-A-timeout-occurred). Outro detalhe sobre o CF é que ele não suporta socket, teríamos então problemas com [stream e websocket](https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&query=socket%20support&commit=Search) por exemplo.

Caso o Cloudflare não seja uma opção, você deve optar por um servidor que tenha tanto IPv4 como IPv6 e configurar corretamente seu DNS com entradas "A" para o IPv4 e entradas "AAAA" para o IPv6, além de configurar teu servidor para receber conexões IPv6(camada de rede) e seu seu servidor web (Camada de aplicação) para responder por este IPv6.

Como você está utilizando o Embarcadero xe10, é necessário entender como ele trata essa questão, pois o código será reescrito e nesse processo de reescrita deve-se estar adequado às especificações fornecidas pela apple.

Answer (score 0):

> Ele foi **recusado por não ter suporte a IPV6**.
>
> Entrei no site http://validador.ipv6.br/index.php?site=www.useunic.com.br&lang=pt e **verifiquei que não tem suporte a acesso por IPV6**.
>
> A Apple **exige que meu aplicativo funcione em uma rede Ipv6**, conforme site acima.
>
> Nesse host hospedamos apenas os arquivos php que são utilizados no app, existe alguma configuração que podemos fazer para corrigir isso, pois **entrei em contato com a hospedagem e eles não tem suporte ipv6**.

A resposta está na própria pergunta.

Tem um comentário aqui dizendo que remover um registro AAAA no seu servidor DNS poderia resolver o problema. Não acredito que isso vá resolver, pois o registro AAAA é o que garante a correta resolução de um endereço ipv6. Ainda assim, acho que seu provedor atual não o suportará.

Só tem um jeito: encontre um host que possa hospedar sua aplicação. Empresas que fazem isso existem aos montes, e a hospedagem é relativamente barata. Você vai ter um esforço de algumas horas de migração, mas dessa forma você garante o seu negócio.

Se quiser uma lista de sugestões, [este wiki](https://www.sixxs.net/wiki/IPv6_Enabled_Hosting) lista algumas dúzias de empresas ao redor do mundo que têm serviço de hosting com ipv6 (nativo, sem gambiarras).

Comment: Essa restrição vai além do servidor IPv6, há restrições do código, a aplicação não deve ter em seus constructors nenhum tipo de referência específica a IPv4.